# What to do when visiting Kivrei Tzaddikim?

Tags: minhag, travel, cemetery-grave, tzaddikim

When visiting Kevarim of Tzaddikim, when are proper procedures to follow?

I would hope an answer would cover:

- What and how to daven
- If there's any specific Tehillim to say
- If one should (or must) light a candle, place a stone on the grave, or the like

Comment: There is an entire Sefer written about this by Rav Salman Mutzafi ZSWQ"L and it is called "Sifte Hachamim."

Answer (score 2):

[Maaneh Loshon](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/91379/jewish/Maaneh-Lashon.htm) is the text compiled by [the "Mitteler Rebbe" of Lubavich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovber_Schneuri) to say by the grave of his father the "Alter Rebbe".

This text is edited for recital by the graves of the Lubavicher Rebbes in Queens.
It contains instructions, as to [when](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/92061/jewish/Blessings.htm) to light the lamp, [what](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/92061/jewish/Blessings.htm) to say when lighting, etc.

http://hebrewbooks.org/15693 is the text in Hebrew.

Comment: Maaneh Lashon actually goes back a good deal before that: the foreword there [mentions](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/91380/jewish/Publishers-Foreword.htm) that it was first published in Prague around 1610. I don't know whether the Mitteler Rebbe actually changed the text in any way, or simply had it reprinted with specific reference to the Alter Rebbe.

Answer (score -1):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 128:13 writes what pasukim to say and how to place your left hand on the Kever etc see below:
Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, 128:13

[יג] נוֹהֲגִין לֵילֵךְ בְּעֶרֶב רֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה אַחַר תְּפִלַּת שַׁחֲרִית לְבֵית הַקְּבָרוֹת לְהִשְׁתַּטֵּחַ עַל קִבְרֵי הַצַּדִּיקִים וְנוֹתְנִים שָׁם צְדָקָה לַעֲנִיִּים וּמַרְבִּים תַּחֲנוּנִים לְעוֹרֵר אֶת הַצַּדִּיקִים הַקְּדוֹשִׁים אֲשֶׁר בָּאָרֶץ הֵמָּה, שֶׁיַּמְלִיצוּ טוֹב בַּעֲדֵנוּ בְּיוֹם הַדִּין, וְגַם מֵחֲמַת שֶׁהוּא מְקוֹם קְבוּרַת הַצַּדִּיקִים, הַמָּקוֹם הוּא קָדוֹשׁ וְטָהוֹר וְהַתְּפִלָּה מְקֻבֶּלֶת שָׁם בְּיוֹתֵר בִּהְיוֹתָהּ עַל אַדְמַת קֹדֶשׁ, וְיַעֲשֶֹה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא חֶסֶד בִּזְכוּת הַצַּדִּיקִים. אֲבָל אַל יָשִֹים מְגַמָּתוֹ נֶגֶד הַמֵּתִים הַשּׁוֹכְנִים שָׁם, כִּי קָרוֹב הַדָּבָר שֶׁיִּהְיֶה בִּכְלַל "וְדוֹרֵשׁ אֶל הַמֵּתִים", אַךְ יְבַקֵּשׁ מֵהַשֵּׁם יִתְבָּרֵךְ שֶׁיְּרַחֵם עָלָיו בִּזְכוּת הַצַּדִּיקִים שׁוֹכְנֵי עָפָר. כְּשֶׁבָּא אֶל בֵּית הַקְּבָרוֹת, אִם לֹא רָאָה אֶת הַקְּבָרִים שְׁלשִׁים יוֹם צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ, אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין וְכֻלֵּי (לְעֵיל סִימָן ס' סָעִיף י"א), כְּשֶׁבָּא אֶל הַקֶּבֶר, יֵשׁ לוֹ לוֹמַר, יְהִי רָצוֹן שֶׁתְּהֵא מְנוּחָתוֹ שֶׁל (פְּלוֹנִי) הַקָּבוּר פֹּה בְּכָבוֹד וּזְכוּתוֹ יַעֲמֹד לִי. כְּשֶׁמֵּשִֹים יָדוֹ עַל הַקֶּבֶר, יֵשׁ לָשֹוּם יַד שְֹמֹאלוֹ דַּוְקָא וְלֹא יְמִינוֹ, וְיֹאמַר אֶת הַפָּסוּק, וְנָחֲךָ ה' תָּמִיד וְהִשְֹבִּיעַ בְּצַחְצָחוֹת נַפְשֶׁךָ וְעַצְמוֹתֶיךָ יַחֲלִיץ וְהָיִיתָ כְּגַן רָוֶה וּכְמוֹצָא מַיִם אֲשֶׁר לֹא יְכַזְּבוּ מֵימָיו, תִּשְׁכַּב בְּשָׁלוֹם, וְתִישַׁן בְּשָׁלוֹם, עַד בֹּא מְנַחֵם מַשְׁמִיעַ שָׁלוֹם. (וּכְשֶׁמֵּשִֹים יָדוֹ יְכַוֵּן בְּפָסוּק "וְנָחֳךָ" שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ חֲמִשָּׁה עָשָֹר תֵּבוֹת כְּמִנְיַן קִשְׁרֵי הַיָּד ׀ בִּרְכֵּי יוֹסֵף סִימָן רכ"ד). אֵין לֵילֵךְ עַל קֶבֶר אֶחָד שְׁתֵּי פְּעָמִים בְּיוֹם אֶחָד. הַקּוֹרֵא כְּתָב שֶׁעַל גַּבֵּי הַמַּצֵבָה, אִם הוּא כְּתָב בּוֹלֵט קָשֶׁה לְשִׁכְחָה. וּסְגוּלָה לוֹמַר "אַהֲבָה רַבָּה" עַד "וּלְיַחֶדְךָ בְּאַהֲבָה":

Comment: You should at least summarize in Engkish if not translate.